How to uninstall faulty/strange programs?
I tried to install the Fusion360 vsnap package. The installation seemed to work, but the program wouldn't work properly, so I uninstalled fusion360 over the software-center, which worked too, but I'm now stuck with this leftover program. It is part of fusion36, but it does not disappear.
I tried uninstalling fusion360 in the terminal and to remove all dependencies with both autoremove and remove --purge (If that's what it does), restarted my laptop, and tried to find the package name. I couldn't find anything I could link to this program. There's no package with a similar name).
How do I remove it?


Please edit your post and add exact information how you installed Fusion 360, e.g. where did you click what and / or which commands you executed.
Please also add the output of snap list --all to your question.

If you really installed Fusion360 via snap, trying to remove it via apt won't work, as it is a different system. Removal of snap packages is done either via sudo snap remove NAME_OF_THE_SNAP or via an appropriate GUI tools. Removing can technically leave no artefacts / orphaned programs, unless other snaps have been installed as dependencies of the Fusion360 snap.
Please provide the output of snap list --all.
